# Why would my import of multiple selections work in one content type but not the other?

Tags: importing-exporting

I've got two content types that both have one off CSV file imports. They both have fields where you can select multiple values. The csv is comma delimited and the multiple selection data, for the field in question, is separated from the rest of the data by quotation marks, within the quotation marks there are no spaces between values; each value is instead comma separated.

For one of the content types this works perfectly, multiple values are put into the field. This field is a node reference.

However for the other content type this doesn't work instead if there are multiple values in the csv no values are given to the content, there are no error messages in any logs. This field is a multi check-box/radio input. I've checked and double checked to make sure the are no spelling discrepancies and I've ensured the field is set up correctly. If you manually create a new node of this content type you can allocate multiple values within this field.

Both fields are set to take unlimited values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually finding no solution to the problem I decided to replicate the multiple field selection import that was working.

I made a new content type which contained nothing but the data items I wanted to be able to select and then used a node reference from the original content type. This isn't the most opportune method as whenever this data is displayed it is displayed as a link, a link which then takes you to a page which has nothing on it apart from the name of the data. However imports correctly put the desired data into the the field.

My suspicions regarding this issue are around how the node reference handles multi-fields. Perhaps handling them in a similar way to the import, as in [datafield1,dataf2,"dataf3,dataf3,dataf3",dataf4](as clarification, the previous example is how the csv is laid out). However I've no idea whether or not this actually has any grounds.